# Build a list from array object sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to sencha touch and trying to build a list from an array. I use `Ext.data.ArrayStore` and having trouble.

My code:

```js
var ListStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({       
    autoLoad:myData,    
    autoDestroy: true,
    storeId: 'myStore',
    // reader configs
    idIndex: 0,
    fields: [
       'product',
       {name: 'product', type: 'string'},
       {name: 'id'     , type: 'string'}

    ]       
});
```

Code of the Panel which includes the list:

```js
var listPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                ui: 'light',
                title: 'Product List',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Back',
                    ui: 'back',
                    handler: backHandler
                }]
            }],
            layout: 'fit',
            scroll: 'vertical',
            style: 'background-color:#FFFFF',
            items: [
            {
                xtype:'list',
                store:ListStore,
                itemTpl: '<div class="product"><strong>{product}</strong></div>',
                grouped:true,
                indexBar:true
            }]
```

Comment: what is the problem or output your getting ?

Comment: You really have to tell us what errors you get or what results are wrong if you want somebody to help you. Nobody can help if you don't explain the problem.

Comment: Basically, I get a json object from a web service and I want to build a list using sencha touch. i try to find any proper example how to do that and didn't find any. SO, if you can give an example i'll be glad

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I found an example how to build a simple list with "static" data.
I want to replace the static data with an array from var..

Comment: the error that i get is:
DataView requires tpl,store and itemSelector
configuration to be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [Swar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417311/swar)'s answer seems perfectly correct. Create a store like that, pass your data as the `data` config option when creating an `Ext.data.Store` instance.

If you've `Ext.define()`-ed your own store subclass (without a proxy), you can either add the data when you `create()` your instance, like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extends: 'Ext.data.store',
    model: 'Demo'
});

myStore = MyApp.store.MyStore({data: arrayOfDemoItems});
```

Or altertanively, if you already have a store instance (e.g. auto-created by a controller):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['MyStore'],
    init: function () {
        // You add your items here
        var myStore = this.getMyStoreStore();
        myStore.data.addAll(this.getMyItemsSomehow(););
        // Note that the 'load' event is not fired if you load elements like this,
        // you have to do it manually if you have e.g. a DataView tied to the store:
        myStore.fireEvent('load', myStore);
    },
    getMyItemsSomehow: function () {
        // Return an array of items somehow...
        return [{id: 1, product: 'Spencer'}];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model first.

```
Ext.regModel('Demo', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'product',  type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Then create the store:

```
new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Demo',
    data : [
        {id: '1',    product: 'Spencer'}
    ]
});
```

And as far I can understand from your code, in "autoLoad" option of Store, it should boolean or object which is not the data but options for the store load() method.

Comment: I have tried to do that with autoLoad without success...
In short i want to replace the data with an array\json object that contain my data.
P.S 
I already fetch the json object and i don't need to use proxy...

Comment: Can you share the data format you are using here. And put your latest store definition too.